# tornado asynchronous post multipart

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, tornado

I'm using Tornado and I need to make asynchronous POST multipart request. In the web I found something from flickr api, but didn't understand how to use it. So, how can I post image through the HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

Tornado doesn't currently provide any utilities to create multipart-formatted requests; you'll have to encode the request yourself. The standard library's [email.mime.multipart](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.mime.html#email.mime.multipart.MIMEMultipart) module may help you do this if you pass `form-data` as the `subtype` argument, although I haven't personally verified that this works for web requests (or how the subparts need to be formatted).

Once you have a multipart-encoded payload, simply pass it as the `body` argument to `AsyncHTTPClient.fetch`.